# How to write text into the file saved on server in swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, string, file-io

I am trying to write some text to the file on Server. Text file server path is:

```
http://test.info.com/log.txt
```

So, whatever we will write on this text file can able to see in browser. Please anyone suggest me.

Comment: I have checked https://github.com/awseeley/Read-Write-Text-File-Swift-Tutorial but this is to read and write to local text files.

Comment: You need to upload it. There is no on the fly write possible

Comment: Just create local log.txt and write down you want and upload it to server. You can't write into the server file directly!!!

Comment: Yes, we can read/write into local log.txt file, Is there any other way to write on Server file. Server is giving me that file path?

Comment: @user3344236What I have to upload?

Comment: This isn't a Swift backend app is it? you mean you want to show client/device logs on the server?

Comment: Hi @ScriptableYes you are right, this we are doing to fetch Client device logs. Can you please suggest me..

Answer (score 1):

In one word, There is no on the fly write possible from mobile to server file.

## Justification:

**Question:**

> What's happen if I paste the logfile URL(http://test.info.com/log.txt)
> into the browser?

**Answer:**

> It will just download the log.txt file. Also, It will not allow doing
> direct editing in the browser too. If it will is not feasible from the browser So how can we do it from the mobile end?

**Alternatives:**

Recently I worked with the same type of requirements. I have achieved it by creating the local `log.txt` file. Write into this file. Every day, I have uploaded the same log file into the server.

To write into the log file, I have used [SwiftLog(Simple and easy logging in Swift)](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftLog)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 APIs on the server where your text file is kept. One API to get the data of the text file. Once that is done, show it in a TextView and edit it.

After editing, you can call another api to send the updated data back to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your response @kerry, I don't have to call any APIs to do this. Any other way?

Comment: There is no other way. You have to get the data and edit and upload it back.

Comment: Noted with Thanks!